# Jquery append() doesn't work on new <a>Add</a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Append() working fine but it is working only on the first `<a class="add">Add</a>`. not able to add new input field with the latest `<a class="add">Add</a>`

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    $('.add').click(function() { 
        $("#add_words").append('<div class="line">Word is <input type="text" /><a class="add">Add</a></div>');
        return false;
    });
});
```

html code

```
<div id="add_words">
    <div class="line">Word is 1<input class="input1" type="text" value="1" /><a class="add">Add</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Live like this: [see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnHd5/5/)

```
$('.add').live("click", function(event) {      
    $("#add_words").append('<div class="line">Word is <input type="text" /><a class="add">Add</a></div>');
    return false;
```

});

Comment: [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated. You should use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead, as noted in my answer and others.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `click` only attaches the `click` event handler to existing DOM elements, not future ones. You need jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_words").on("click", ".add", function(e) {
     // Do your append here
     // e.delegateTarget is your <div id="add_words">
     $(e.delegateTarget).append('<div class="line">Word is <input type="text" /><a class="add">Add</a></div>');
     // Prevent default action (e.g. don't follow links)
     e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `on()` for event delegation instead of `click()`:

```
$('#add_words').on('click', '.add', function(){
    $("#add_words").append('<div class="line">Word is <input type="text" /><a class="add">Add</a></div>');
});
```